# Map method in javascript gives a syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm experiencing a syntax error on my `map` function that says:

```
',' expected
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Products extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    cart: []
   }
}
render () {
const { products } = this.props;
return (
  <>
   <thead>
     <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
       {
         products.map((product, key) => {
              (product.title)
        }
    </thead>
  </>
  )
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're accepting `props` into your component. Therefor, `props` will be undefined, as well as `products`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the value correctly for jsx within a map function. Try this:

```
{
   products.map((product, key) => (
       <th key={key}>
         { product.title }
       </th>
      ))
 }
```

Using the parenthesis rather than the curly brackets will treat it as a returned expression. Whereas, if you use curly brackets, you'd need to `return` the expression (jsx) explicitly, like this:

```
{
   products.map((product, key) => {
      return (
       <th key={key}>
         { product.title }
       </th>
      )
    })
 }
```

Comment: You are one ) short.

Comment: @Erik Whoops. Thought I already fixed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```js
 {products.map((product) => (
          <td> {product.title}</td>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you map `products` here

```
                    {products.map((product, key) => {
                      (product.title)
                    })}
```

You are not returning anything in the callback function of map.
So you should make it to be

```
                    {products.map((product, key) => (
                      (product.title)
                    ))}
```

change { to ( , } to ) so the callback function returning `product.title`